Interchanging a Particular Double-Sum
Consider the double-sum
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=i}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} f(i,j)$$
where $x\ge 0$ and $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ denotes the floor function. I would like to write this sum in the form
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor}\sum_{j=0}^i f(i,j),$$ but I am confused on how this can done. Is this an application of Fubini's theorem? Any advice would be appreciated.

Assuming  for example $x =10$, your first expression includes $f(2,7)$ in the sum but not $f(7,2)$ while your second expression is the other way round.  If you had written $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor}\sum\limits_{j=0}^i f(j,i)$ for the second expression, then it would be equal to the first expression.

This is actually a finite sum, equal to
$$\sum_{0\le i\le j\le\lfloor x \rfloor} f(i,j)=\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor}\sum_{i=0}^jf(i,j),$$
instead of what you would like.

Maybe it's just too late in the night, but I don't completely understand how $i$ now runs from $0$ to $j$.

The conditions $0\le i<\infty\land i\le j\le N$ are equivalent to $0\le i\le j\le N$, i.e. $0\le j\le N\land0\le i\le j.$ Good night!

To explain it another way, $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is a constant with respect to the doubly-indexed sum and can be represented by an arbitrary natural number $N$. When evaluating $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=i}^{\lfloor x\rfloor}f(i,j)$, once $i>N$, we start adding $0$ because there are no natural numbers $k$ satisfying $N+k\leq j\leq N$ (this is called an empty sum). Therefore, the true upper bound is $\lfloor x\rfloor$, not $\infty$. The index reordering follows trivially.

I see. Thank you!

It is not a finite sum! It's just that the partial sums are constant after a while, thus in this case convergence is a trivial matter.

It is (or at least, it reduces to) a finite sum @Jannik, as explained in the answer and the comments, in particular the detailed rewording by teadawg. So, no convergence problem indeed, and the remaining (easy) task was only to "interchange in a finite double-sum".

Out of curiosity, if $x$ depends on $j$ (e.g. $x+j$) does this change the convergence properties of the double sum?

$x$ cannot depend on $j$: $N:=\lfloor x\rfloor$ is given, and $i,j$ are dummy variables taking all possible values such that $0\le i\le j\le N$.
